# Stopping a php script that's running in the background

Tags: php, background, daemon, kill

I've been following some tutorials on running and managing php scrips as background process. I've been playing with the script below.

```
<?php
$count = 0;
while(true){
    $count = $count + 1;
    file_put_contents('daemon1.log', $count, FILE_APPEND);
    sleep(1);

}
?>
```

When I run this navigating to it's url in a browser window and I then close the window it seems to keep running. Is this typical of php scripts? How do I stop this process once it's running int he background?

Comment: Yes it is typically the basic behaviour, but know that there is a execution time limit (with a default value to 30s) that can be changed with `set_time_limit` function

Answer (score 0):

> When I run this navigating to its URL in a browser window and I then close the window it seems to keep running. Is this typical of PHP scripts?

It will keep running because it's still *working*.

It will die when a maximum execution time or memory limit is hit.

> How do I stop this process once it's running in the background?

To stop it, use a construct such as `exit`.

Comment: You are not really responding to the question. He don't ask how to stop the script, he ask how to stop the script when the client disconnect to the server

Comment: @MatRt *he ask how to stop the script when the client disconnect to the server* Where was that mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is typically the basic behaviour, but know that there is a execution time limit (with a default value to 30s) that can be changed with `set_time_limit` function

If you want to manage that kind of configuration, take a look at

```
ignore_user_abort
```

that will allow you to configure if you want to ignore or not user abort.
You can also check the client status with

```
connection_aborted
```

[connection_aborted documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php)

[ignore_user_abort documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)